# Get all room names from one plan view and change a parameter of each room | Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

right now I am working on a project, which should get the roomnames from a plan view and compare each room name with a database. If the roomname if found in the database, the parameter in the room called "IS_IN_DATABASE" should be updated with "YES"

Unfortunately  I have no Idea, how to get the roomnames from one plan view...

I found this post: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-retrieve-rooms-filtered-by-level/td-p/6627076 
but it does not work because I always get a exception:

viewId is not a view.
Parameter name: viewId

Comment: As the post mentioned: `You need to make sure the active view is not the project browser nor
schedule nor draft... it is preferable to be a plan view.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered in the [Revit API discussion forum thread on getting room names and changing parameter value](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/get-all-room-names-from-one-plan-view-and-change-the-parameter/td-p/7989064).

It would be better if you raised separate questions for these two separate issues.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do if you provided some code, but does this work?

```
View activeView = doc.ActiveView;

List<Room> rooms = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, activeView.Id).OfClass(typeof(Room)).Cast<Room>().ToList();
```

To get only the names in a list you could use something like this:

```
List<string> rooms = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, activeView.Id).OfClass(typeof(Room)).Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
```

Put `using Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture` on top, otherwise it won't recognize rooms.

Comment: thank you, but how can I now set a new parameter to the room?

Comment: do you know the name of the parameter?